# access resource text from markup page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, localization

I'm creating an web application with multiple languages.
I've set the culture like this

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(selectedLanguage);
```

I've got several language files like "en.resx" and "de.resx".
I can read them from my code behind them like this

```
var test = GetGlobalResourceObject(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.ToString(), "aboutUsLnk");
```

But how about from the markup page.
I've been searching the web and most pages is suggesting something like this

```
<asp:Literal Text='<%$ Resources:Resource, aboutUsLnk %>' runat="server" />
```

That works if I have a .resx file called Resource but i that's not what I want. What did I miss?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3):

> *That works if I have a .resx-file called Resource but i thats not what I want. What did I miss?*

You are probably looking for local resources and **meta:resourcekey** attribute.

Local are defined per page (you define exactly the same name as your page for them), you use them for storing resources specific to one page. You create them by adding ASP.NET specific folder (App_LocalResources) and then inside it local resources for each of your pages:

```
App_LocalResources/{pagename}.resx
```

And then call for resource objects from resource files (AboutUs.resx, AboutUs.fr-BE.resx,...) from the page markup (AboutUs.aspx) would be something like this:

```
<asp:Literal Text='About Us' meta:resourcekey="aboutUsLnk" runat="server" />
```

Global resources which you mentioned are defined accros the whole website (usually you store here resources like "Edit", "Save", etc.) and are usually called as you showed.

Read here for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163566.aspx

**EDIT**

Ahh sorry for misunderstanding, you are probably asking how to call your global resources which names differentiate per culture. You can do that in your markup code almost the same as you are doing in code behind, using `GetGlobalResourceObject`.

Anywhere outside of server controls you can write:

```
<%= GetGlobalResourceObject(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.ToString(), "aboutUsLnk")%>
```

To call `GetGlobalResourceObject` inside of server control attributes you cannot use `<%= %>`, but you can wrap the server controls around it (in the ones that allow this, like `Label` for example):

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"><%= GetGlobalResourceObject(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.ToString(), "aboutUsLnk")%></asp:Label>
```

Or, you can use the binding syntax:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# GetGlobalResourceObject(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.ToString(), "aboutUsLnk")%>'></asp:Label>
```

Note, that when using the latter you will need to bind your control:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Label1.DataBind();
}
```

**EDIT 2**

You can wrap the upper code in some helper method to improve code readabilty. In code behind you declare it:

```
protected string GetResource(string resourceName)
{
   return GetGlobalResourceObject(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.ToString(), resourceName).ToString();
}
```

And in markup you can call it similiar as previous:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# GetResource("aboutUsLnk")%>'></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"><%= GetResource("aboutUsLnk")%></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to use Global Resources not Local. I want one file per language

Comment: Thank you, now it works. It's a very long code though, isn't it also possible to do it like i Wrote? Anyhow, big thanks.

Comment: @WIRN: I am not aware of any shorter way. I added second edit which can help you (to make it a little prettier and readable)

Comment: I've bin using your suggestion now for about 3 weeks and it totally made google drop my site in SEO. It made my site give 500 Internal Server Errors but I could still surf the page but the crawlers could not...

Comment: @WIRN: huh, interesting. Did you try [Fetch as Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/158587?hl=en) in Webmasters Tools?

Comment: Jepp. My web hotel provider sent me an email (after I wrote the last post) with the exception. It was: "Exception type: MissingManifestResourceException 
Exception message: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture. Make sure "Resources.bg.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "App_GlobalResources.kdel7usn" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed."